# laravel- How to create separate registration form in the same view?

Tags: laravel

I created a registration form using `make:auth` in laravel and I made some changes to it like below:

[image]

I want to create three separate registration forms(each form has slightly different inputs) such as normal user, special user, super user for example. So that any user can select the registration category they want. I read about spatie in laravel but I am only looking to a way to be able for user to choose the registration form and it changes accordingly on the same page.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can be modifying `resources/auth/register.blade.php`  with jquery create a dropdown where user can change the type and according to type hide/show html.

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya Any resource showing how to do this?

Comment: No there is not any resource in my mind right now. You can do with custom logic.
Please explain what type of field coming in three different forms.

Comment: any idea where to get free template for simple dashboard for laravel? I need to create one for when a supplier login.